# Moving away from nested ifs to allow for more filter options

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm hoping I can get some help in improving the approach that I'm currently using to Sum and Count rows of data based on filters my users can select.

Currently I have 7 filters that I check to see if I should include a row in the calculation. We want to add additional filters, but I'm not bumping up against the maximum nested ifs. I'm also concerned I may have bugs in my formula due to it's complexity.

So each row of data has characteristics (sales data) that I am checking to see if I should include the row in the calculation. So a row of data would have the following types of characteristics that I filter against:

Deal type (all, new, renewal, or addon), Region (all, east, west, central), Competitor (all, then specific competitor names), Date filter (start date and end date), and Deal size (start size and end size).

Then we have identified why we won or lost the deal across a spectrum of characteristics. We indicate if a characteristic was a cause of the deal outcome with the use of "1" in the cell for losses and "0" for wins. So I have columns entitled Price, proposal, presentation, company references, etc.

If we lost a deal and we believe we lost the deal because of price and references, I would have a 1 in each of those columns for that row of data.

Then I have a summary section where I am trying to figure out how many deals we have lost due to "price" (I count the number of 1s that also meet the filter criteria) and how much revenue we lost due to price (same formula, but I sum the deal size instead of count deals).

Hopefully, this gives a you a good idea of what I'm working with. I'd like to be able to enhance the formulas so that I can add additional filters as needed as well as simplify it if possible to make it easier to maintain.

The formula that I'm using now to count losses for a specific reason looks like the following (it's basically the same formula for wins, but I count zeros instead of ones):

```
=IF(AND($CU$1="ALL", $CR$2="ALL", $CU$2="ALL"),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2),
IF(AND($CU$1="ALL", $CR$2="ALL", NOT($CU$2="ALL")),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$D$7:$D$1000,"="&$CU$2),
    IF(AND($CU$1="ALL", NOT($CR$2="ALL"), $CU$2="ALL"),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$K$7:$K$1000,"="&$CR$2),
        IF(AND(NOT($CU$1="ALL"), $CR$2="ALL", $CU$2="ALL"),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$M$7:$M$1000,"="&$CU$1),
            IF(AND(NOT($CU$1="ALL"), NOT($CR$2="ALL"), $CU$2="ALL"),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$M$7:$M$1000,"="&$CU$1,$K$7:$K$1000,"="&$CR$2),
                IF(AND(NOT($CU$1="ALL"), NOT($CR$2="ALL"), NOT($CU$2="ALL")),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$M$7:$M$1000,"="&$CU$1,$K$7:$K$1000,"="&$CR$2,$D$7:$D$1000,"="&$CU$2),
                    IF(AND($CU$1="ALL", NOT($CR$2="ALL"), NOT($CU$2="ALL")),COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$D$7:$D$1000,"="&$CU$2,$K$7:$K$1000,"="&$CR$2),
                        COUNTIFS($Y$7:$Y$1000,"=1",$A$7:$A$1000,">="&$CN$1,$A$7:$A$1000,"<="&$CP$1,$J$7:$J$1000,">="&$CN$2,$J$7:$J$1000,"<="&$CP$2,$M$7:$M$1000,"="&$CU$1,$D$7:$D$1000,"="&$CU$2))))))))
```

So for each outcome reason (price, proposal, references, etc.) I have to duplicate this formula four times. Once for counting losses, once for summing losses, once for counting wins, and once for summing wins.

The end result is I get a table that looks like the following:

```
Decision Driver | Win Frequency | Won Revenue | Loss Frequency | Lost Revenue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Price           | 23            | $230,000    |  12            |  $165,000
Proposal        | 12            | $140,000    |  16            |  $195,000
etc...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using sumifs and countifs, have you looked into sumproduct? Or why not try.. **a pivot table!**

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to roll your own pivot table. No need to reinvent the wheel.